# What does "The ArcGIS Server Object Manager service hung on starting" indicate?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-server

I often get this error message in the Windows 2008 R2 server event logs:
*The ArcGIS Server Object Manager service hung on starting. (EventID: 7022)*

Have tried searching the cause for this error but noluck yet.
Any ideas?

S/W specs:

- ArcGIS Server Advaced Enterprise 10 SP4

Regards
Ujjwal

Comment: when do u get the message? on server startup or just random?  Can u correlate it to any messages in the ags logs at the same period of time?

Comment: It does not happen on every server restart...only sometimes and randomly. Logs do not reflect any abnormal activity. PS: Logging in not verbose in the production system

Answer (score 1):

@Ujjwal Please check the following things

1.Such as windows firewall and Check out Local security policy as well as DCOM settings (I assume that you have admin rights) 
Not sure but I think the SOM component is installed on your machine so if yes then manually type the SOM account password then restart machine.

2.Try to access Server Manager URL from different machine and browser

3.If IT Admin permits then add ArcGIS-SOC,ArcGIS-SOM,ArcGIS-Webservice accounts to administrator group &then restart the machine  I am sure it will resolve the issue..Please

let us know if you require additional help..thanks all the best

Comment: Why would anyone need to "add ArcGIS-SOC,ArcGIS-SOM,ArcGIS-Webservice accounts to administrator group" ? What problem do you believe this would be solving?

Comment: This is one of the workaround mentioned by Esri.. & it works because some  times permissions are not properly assigned.

Comment: If permissions are not properly assigned, then giving those account Level 2 access is probably not the most secure course of action. If this machine is inside a corporate Firewall, this might be acceptable, but if this machine is in a DMZ or internet-accessible, I would highly recommend against this practice for security reasons.

Comment: @Sunil: ArcGIS SOM/SOC permissions is not the issue, otherwise it would not ahve renederd the output at all. The service is working absulutely fine, just that occasionally it would hung while starting.

Comment: I read about DCOM permissions in one of the ESRI discussions, and modified the same for ArcSOM.exe on the problem server. I need to monitor it for sometime to establish if it has fixed the issue.

Comment: @ujjwalesri great !! I will keep my finger cross : )